# Interface implementation inexplicably converting List<T> to List<Libary.T> C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm having trouble implementing this functionality as being derived from a generic method in C# .NET Core 2.0.1 as follows:

Interface

```
public interface IListable 
{
    List<T> AsList<T>();
}
```

Implementation

```
public class PwActivityTypeCollection : IListable 
{
    public List<PwActivityType> user;
    public List<PwActivityType> system;
    public List<PwActivityType> AsList<PwActivityType>() 
    {
      return user.Concat (system).ToList();
    }
}
```

Note that this worked fine as follows before I tried to implement the interface.  The `Concat` code returns `List<PwActivityType>` as expected:

```
public List<PwActivityType> AsList() 
{
    return user.Concat(system).ToList();
}
```

Error:

> PwActivityType.cs(16,14): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Library.PwActivityType>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PwActivityType>' [/Users/shanekenyon/Documents/git/gls_int_prosperworks/library/library.csproj]

Comment: The `AsList` method in the interface is meant to be generic - your method isn't generic. (Admittedly it's pretty odd that it's meant to be generic - what would you expect to happen if someone called `AsList<Guid>` for example?)

Comment: Following on from Daisy's comment your code `AsList<PwActivityType>` is actually saying "I am declaring a method called `AsList` which has a generic parameter called `PwActivityType`". That is where normally a generic method might have `T` as its generic parameter name you are using `PwActivityType`. If you then read your error as being akin to "`'System.Collections.Generic.List<Library.PwActivityType>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'` " then it might explain this seemingly confusing error message.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you really want is to make your interface generic rather than the method, for example:

```
public interface IListable<T>
{
    List<T> AsList();
}
```

Which makes your class something like this:

```
public class PwActivityTypeCollection : IListable<PwActivityType>
{
    public List<PwActivityType> user;
    public List<PwActivityType> system;

    public List<PwActivityType> AsList()
    {
        return user.Concat(system).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Define `IListable<out T>` as [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance#InterfaceCovariantTypeParameters) type to greater flexibility.